# I am getting an Invalid API call from Alpha Vantage TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED for Mexico or Toronto Stocks (with a period). Why?

Tags: programming, tick-data

I have used the following:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=URBI&apikey=nnnnnnnnn

I get back this:

```
{
    "bestMatches": [
        {
            "1. symbol": "URBDF",
            "2. name": "Urbi, Desarrollos Urbanos, S.A.B. de C.V.",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7273"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "URBI.MEX",
            "2. name": "Urbi, Desarrollos Urbanos, S.A.B. de C.V.",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "Mexico",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:30",
            "6. marketClose": "15:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-06",
            "8. currency": "MXP",
            "9. matchScore": "0.6667"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "4GP.FRK",
            "2. name": "Urbi, Desarrollos Urbanos, S.A.B. de C.V.",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "Frankfurt",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "20:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+01",
            "8. currency": "EUR",
            "9. matchScore": "0.1778"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I want to query URBI.MEX.

I do this:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=URBI.MEX&apikey=nnnnnn

I get back this:

```
{
    "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED."
}
```

Why? URBI.MEX is in their catalog I would assume, judging by the first API call.

Have tried URBI.MX, URBI-MX, URBI-MEX to no avail.

Comment: Can you retrieve the data using a browser?

Comment: No. Tried various browsers. Same response: Invalid API call.

I've been emailing them for a week now. No response. Just wondering if anyone has had luck. I tried another example (here on Stack Exchange) with a ticker having a period (Indian market), and it worked. But no luck with Toronto or Mexico...

Comment: assuming you've checked they api key is correct, I'd double check the documentation or wait for vendor response.  it may be useful to see if you can't find a single circumstance at work to back out what doesn't in your case.  that said, I have had issues with vendors only to find out there's a waiting period and after some hours or days, the previous call works without issue.

Comment: I can replicate the issue. `TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED` works for a few American symbols I tried, but not *URBI.MEX*. Oddly, *URBI.MEX* works for `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY`.

Comment: i have the same issue with IBOV.SAO, it's appears in the search but not when i put the symbol...